# Jump is to vault as jog is to ____ ?

Tags: analogy

This is a “verbal analogies” question, in case it is not clear of what it is, review the first two words and determine how they are related, select the word from the available answers that has the same relationship with the third word.

Original question: jump → vault, jog → ?

Available answers: train, trot, compete, sprint, run

My question - the correct answer is “sprint”, my daughter and I both chose “trot”. can somebody explain why? My understanding is this, jump and vault are synonym as verb, both mean “leap”. “jog” and “trot” both mean running in slow pace. Sprint would be opposite of jog, wouldn’t it?

Comment: Learning a second language (which I assume is what you are doing) is hard enough without having to puzzle over contrived questions.  The question you are puzzling over  is simply a bad question.  My sympathies!

Comment: For what it's worth, my immediate two responses were "gallop" and "bound". To vault is to jump energetically a single time over a thing. It makes no sense at all to jog a single time, but to jog more energetically is to gallop (which carries the same up-and-down motion that jogging has but sprinting lacks), and to jog over something is to bound over it.

Comment: I was thinking "running hand stand" until I saw the choices. You vault with your hands. [Swiss Vaulters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmd-RuYTj5U)

Comment: To vault is to jump over. So the corollary would be to run over. Which is not provided. 'Leap' maybe.

Answer (score 1):

To vault is to jump by means of manual propulsion, or, in a sense, to "jump propulsively." By analogy, if a jog is a kind of run, the only way one could "jog propulsively" would be to jog or run *faster*. The only option among your possible answers that could be characterized as running propulsively is "sprint." A trot is a kind of running that is faster than jogging but slower than sprinting. Therefore, "trot" might be *a* correct answer, but it's not the *best* one.

Comment: I don't think that forward motion is the issue - I'd say that vault is a more propulsive form of jump and that sprint is a more propulsive form of jogging.

Comment: That make sense. "Forward" is an unnecessary qualifier in the definition.